# What does the ammeter reading correspond to in a full-wave rectified DC supply

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics, electric-current

I was doing an experiment where I had to measure the current (using an analogue ammeter) from a DC supply. The DC supply actually provided a full-wave rectified current. I was wondering what the current reading on my ammeter would correspond to. For a regular sine curve it would be the RMS but I don't know what it would be for full-wave rectified AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the instrument you are using. If it's an actual RMS meter, then you are getting RMS, if it's an electromechanical one, then it's more like the average. If you were to professionally design an actual power supply, then knowing the peak current would be required because the actual current flow through the rectifier to charge the capacitors is usually rather short and large, so the peak-to-rms correction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor) tends to be large. One would usually measure the actual waveform with an oscilloscope to make sure that neither the rectifier diodes nor the capacitors are stressed beyond their specified peak currents and that there are healthy margins to ensure reliability.

If you don't have an oscilloscope, then circuit simulation will help. Familiarize yourself with the use of an analog circuit simulator like Spice. LTSpice is a free software that works fine for circuits of this kind. The simulated currents agree usually quite well with the measured ones, so you can estimate the crest factor for your circuit with the simulator and then use that estimate to extrapolate your measured average or RMS value to the actual peak current.

Here is an example voltage and current plot:
[image: Rectifier current and output voltage]

and this is the circuit diagram:
[image]

As you can see the peak current (5A) is five times the average DC current (1A), even for a circuit with a rather high transformer internal resistance (and rather poor efficiency, if I may say).

Just for the fun of it, here is the full wave version:
[image]